# Forcing html element to position side by side using float: left cause a change of length

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to position two element side by side in my html, however it seem like when I do so using `float: left` it cause the second element to change size.

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/75sk76Ni29Hb3WYFnLU6?p=preview)

I tried manually changing the width but the size change seems to ignore the width change.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a space between `500` and `px`, causing the `500px` rule being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I think this might help a bit.

```
.width_modify4{

    float: left;
    width: 140px;

}
```

You have `width: 140px;` set in `.width_modify3` but you set `.width_modify4` to `width: 500 px;` which has a small error: there is a space between `500` and `px`, causing the statement to be ignored. Try removing the space. Hope this helps!

EDIT: After realizing that you might not want to have the two elements be the same size, just do `width: (number of pixels)px`. For instance, `width: 500px`.